# AWS - how to support pause/resume of in-transfer tasks

Tags: ios7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

As per my requirement user shall be able to select multiple files for upload and download, and he shall be able to pause and resume each task individually.

In AWS SDK v.2.0.6 we can use [AWS3TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3TransferManager.html) to upload and download files. If I look at its [class reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3TransferManager.html) I can find that there are two methods:

1. pauseAll
2. resumeAll

but I did not find any method to perform it on individual transfers.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I was using this repo from Github to handle such cases during development of the app that requires this kind of user interaction.

This repo contains all you need.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples

Comment: thanks :) do you have any idea about how can I handle this scenario - user was downloading a big file then he paused it, he quitted the app and on re-launch he wants to resume the paused operation.

Comment: Resuming uploads will start from the beginning if the file you are uploading is less than 5 MB. Resuming uploads will start from the last successfully uploaded 5 MB part if the file is greater than 5 MB. So firstly before killing up you're must save chunk files to be able to resume. It seems to me.